# using modal as submit confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
I currently have a form. As per below. 

<form action="/process" id="formTest"  name="formTest" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

I added a modal to confirm on the submit.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bondModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Test;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" id="accept" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Now if the user submit, the modal of confirmation will be showed, and if the user subsequently choose accept, it will proceed the submit.

The problem is , the subsequent submit never works.

```
$('#formTest').submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
    $('#bondModal').modal('show');

        $("#accept").click(function(e) {
        $("#formTest").submit();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#bondModal').modal('hide');



}

        );
    } });
```

The thing is if I change the code to reset instead of submit..it works for reset ..

```
$('#formTest').trigger('reset');
```

Comment: http://bootboxjs.com/ there you can see confirm dialog example

Comment: I think it might be happening because you are over-riding the `submit` function for that form anyway. So instead of over-riding the `submit` function, try to replace it with the corresponding `submit` button's click function and then try to do the normal submit like `$('#formTest').submit()` in your modal's click function. And there's a typo as well in your code, it should be `document.getElementsbyname()`

Comment: George,  try to skim through bootbox document,  couldn't find anything related to submit within the callback

Comment: Vivek, would you mind elaborating further "try to replace it with corresponding submit button click function '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got yourself stuck in a loop.

When you fire the action:

```
 $("#formTest").submit();
```

You are not submitting the form because you are calling your own function which prevents the default action:

```
$('#formTest').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
});
```

If you want to use the code you have currently you can do 1 of 2 things:

- use one() on the submit function so it only fires once. This would require you to rebind on a reset or cancel

  ```
  $('#formTest').one('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //do stuff
  });
  ```
- Or unbind the submit function just before your forced submission.

  ```
  $('#formTest').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $("#accept").click(function(e) {
          $('#formTest').unbind('submit');
          $('#formTest').submit();
      });
  });
  ```

However, I would go a different way, and take the submit button out of the visible markup on the page. Just put an `a` tag in the form that you fire the `open-modal` function from upon click. Then you don't need to do any submission in your code, you just have the standard submit and reset buttons in the modal and they carry out their default behavior:

The markup:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <a class="open-modal">Submit</a>

        <div class="modal">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm?</h4>
            <p>Test</p>
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the code:

```
    $('a.open-modal').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.modal').fadeIn();
    });
```

Much simpler. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

```
document.getElementbyname("formTest").submit();
```

There is no function called "getElementbyname()". It seems you are looking for `document.getElementsByName()` which returns a NodeList. In that case:

```
document.getElementsByName("formTest")[0].submit();
```

However, you can also use the `document.forms` array:

```
document.forms["formTest"].submit();
```

Finally, since your form has an ID, you could also use that:

```
document.getElementById("formTest").submit();
```

Comment: No luck with that, guess something to do multiple submit there

Comment: I tried getElementbyId  and the javascript console doesnt fire anything

Comment: Copy and paste from my answer because you have another typo if you are doing `getElementbyId`, the B needs to be uppercase.

Comment: Why is your answer in standard JS when the question is in jQuery?

Comment: @DoubleA if you care to take a look at the original question, before OP edited the plain JS out, you'll see why.

Comment: @MrCode So it was. My apologies, if you edit you answer I will remove my -1 (its been more than an hour so my vote is locked)